# Is there a way to the following with one update in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert

This is what we have in the table (CNTRCT_NTFYUSER) now:

| CNTRCT_ID | VERSION_NBR | NOTIFY_TYPE | OPRID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | 1 | A | ExistingUser2 |
| 789 | 1 | A | ExistingUser3 |
| 123 | 2 | A | ExistingUser1 |

We need to insert some additional rows for all CNTRCT_IDs with NOTIFY_TYPE of 'E' and 'R'.

1. Insert 2 rows for all 'ExistingUser#'with NOTIFY_TYPE of 'E' and 'R'
2. Insert 2 additional rows with for each CNTRCT_ID with the OPRID of 'NewUser1' and 'NewUser2'  for each Contract with NOTIFY_TYPE of 'E' and 'R'.

| CNTRCT_ID | VERSION_NBR | NOTIFY_TYPE | OPRID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | 1 | A | ExistingUser2 |
| 456 | 1 | E | ExistingUser2 |
| 456 | 1 | R | ExistingUser2 |
| 456 | 1 | E | NewUser1 |
| 456 | 1 | R | NewUser1 |
| 456 | 1 | E | NewUser2 |
| 456 | 1 | R | NewUser2 |
| 789 | 1 | A | ExistingUser3 |
| 789 | 1 | E | ExistingUser3 |
| 789 | 1 | R | ExistingUser3 |
| 789 | 1 | E | NewUser1 |
| 789 | 1 | R | NewUser1 |
| 789 | 1 | E | NewUser2 |
| 789 | 1 | R | NewUser2 |
| 123 | 2 | A | ExistingUser1 |
| 123 | 2 | E | ExistingUser1 |
| 123 | 2 | R | ExistingUser1 |
| 123 | 2 | E | NewUser1 |
| 123 | 2 | R | NewUser1 |
| 123 | 2 | E | NewUser2 |
| 123 | 2 | R | NewUser2 |

Comment: Are you using Postgresql or Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate:

- "*all 'ExistingUser#'with NOTIFY_TYPE of 'E' and 'R'*", using a `CROSS JOIN` between your <CNTRCT_ID, VERSION_NBR, OPRID> combinations and your possible "*NOTIFY_TYPE*" values (E and R)
- "*for each CNTRCT_ID with the OPRID of 'NewUser1' and 'NewUser2' for each Contract with NOTIFY_TYPE of 'E' and 'R'*", using two `CROSS JOIN` operations on both NOTIFY_TYPE in [E, R] and OPRID in [NewUser1, NewUser2]

Hence, use an `INSERT` statement before your `SELECT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO CNTRCT_NTFYUSER

SELECT CNTRCT_ID, VERSION_NBR, nt.NOTIFY_TYPE, OPRID
FROM CNTRCT_NTFYUSER
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'E' AS NOTIFY_TYPE FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 'R' FROM DUAL) nt

UNION ALL

SELECT CNTRCT_ID, VERSION_NBR, nt.NOTIFY_TYPE, oid.OPRID
FROM CNTRCT_NTFYUSER
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'E' AS NOTIFY_TYPE FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 'R' FROM DUAL) nt
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'NewUser1' AS OPRID FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 'NewUser2' FROM DUAL) oid;
```

Check the Oracle demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cIiYWXDa).

Answer (score 0):

Try this INSERT statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO CNTRCT_NTFYUSER
Select      c1.CNTRCT_ID, c1.VERSION_NBR, x.NOTIFY_TYPE, x.OPRID
From        CNTRCT_NTFYUSER c1
Inner Join  (  SELECT er.NOTIFY_TYPE, usr.OPRID 
               FROM ( (Select 'E' "NOTIFY_TYPE" From Dual UNION ALL Select 'R' "NOTIFY_TYPE" From Dual) er
                      Inner Join (Select 'NewUser1' "OPRID" From Dual UNION ALL Select 'NewUser2' From Dual) usr ON(1 = 1)
                    )
            ) x ON(1 = 1)
```

Where The Inner joined query's result

```sql
SELECT er.NOTIFY_TYPE, usr.OPRID 
               FROM ( (Select 'E' "NOTIFY_TYPE" From Dual UNION ALL Select 'R' "NOTIFY_TYPE" From Dual) er
                      Inner Join (Select 'NewUser1' "OPRID" From Dual UNION ALL Select 'NewUser2' From Dual) usr ON(1 = 1)
                    )

NOTIFY_TYPE OPRID  
----------- --------
E           NewUser1 
E           NewUser2 
R           NewUser1 
R           NewUser2
```

...containes both the new types and new users.

So, with your initial data like here:

```sql
Select * From CNTRCT_NTFYUSER ORDER BY CNTRCT_ID, VERSION_NBR, NOTIFY_TYPE

 CNTRCT_ID VERSION_NBR NOTIFY_TYPE                    OPRID                        
---------- ----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
       123           2 A                              ExistingUser1                  
       456           1 A                              ExistingUser2                  
       789           1 A                              ExistingUser3
```

... the result would be:

```sql
Select * From CNTRCT_NTFYUSER ORDER BY CNTRCT_ID, VERSION_NBR, NOTIFY_TYPE

 CNTRCT_ID VERSION_NBR NOTIFY_TYPE                    OPRID                        
---------- ----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
       123           2 A                              ExistingUser1                  
       123           2 E                              NewUser1                       
       123           2 E                              NewUser2                       
       123           2 R                              NewUser1                       
       123           2 R                              NewUser2                       
       456           1 A                              ExistingUser2                  
       456           1 E                              NewUser1                       
       456           1 E                              NewUser2                       
       456           1 R                              NewUser1                       
       456           1 R                              NewUser2                       
       789           1 A                              ExistingUser3                  
       789           1 E                              NewUser2                       
       789           1 E                              NewUser1                       
       789           1 R                              NewUser1                       
       789           1 R                              NewUser2
```